# Database configuration with WildFly

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, wildfly, jndi

I intend to configure postgresql in my app, but I don't want to manage access to my db through WildFly. Is it possible to avoid this approach and to chose another way but with **jndi**?

Comment: How do you expect to manage your database access?  JNDI could give you parameters but you'll have to create things yourself like the connections, connection pools, and so on.

Comment: @stdunbar, I have a task: postgresql configuration with JNDI (We work with WildFly)

Comment: @IgorGorbunov you already got the solution with jndi

Comment: You need to at least show some pseudo code of what you're trying to achieve. At the moment it looks like you don't know either

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect a postgresql database without abstraction layer such as wildFly, you can use simply jdbc (https://jdbc.postgresql.org/about/about.html) :

> PostgreSQL JDBC Driver (PgJDBC for short) allows Java programs to
>   connect to a PostgreSQL database using standard, database independent
>   Java code. Is an open source JDBC driver written in Pure Java (Type
>   4), and communicates in the PostgreSQL native network protocol.

If you prefer a lightweight ORM ([Object Relational Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)), I would advise activejdbc (http://javalite.io/activejdbc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am interested in setting db with jndi

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the configuration of Wildfly [Wildfly datasource configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/DataSource+configuration) . The datasource can be access with **jndi**. You have to replace the example-jdbc-driver with postgres driver. 
Bellow is my example of configuration of datasource for IBM-informix

```
 <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mvpdb" pool-name="mvpdbpool">
                <connection-url>jdbc:informix-sqli://mars.bza-intern.de:30020/demomvp:informixserver=tcpmars;DB_LOCALE=de_DE.8859-1;IFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT=10;</connection-url>
                <driver>informix</driver>
                <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>3</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>abcd</user-name>
                    <password>efgh</password>
                </security>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
```

The datasource can be access ( Spring context ):

with Java Configuration

```
@Bean(name = "mvpds", autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)
public DataSource Mvpds() {
    logger.info("Mvpds-bean");
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource ds = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:jboss/datasources/mvpdb");
return ds;
 }
```

or XML definition

```
<bean id="mvpds" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName"><value>java:jboss/datasources/mvpdb</value></property>
 </bean>
```

Comment: thanks for responce, my problem was to find the way of db configuration without WildFly but my problem was related with my lack of knowledge of jndi. There is no way to configure db with jndi but without WildFly:)

Answer (score 0):

The question was not correct because of lack of knowledge. The promblem is that no way to configure db without WildFly but with jndi. Jndi is an instrument WildFly uses to find a datasourse:)